# Azure AD integrated MVC application not working after publishing on local IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have created a sample MVC application and configured Azure AD authentication. This creates an application on Azure Portal automatically. When I run this application, it is working fine.

After this, I published the application on IIS and changed reply URL on azure portal and also I changed PostLogoutURL.

When I configure Azure AD in the sample application, a default connection of LocalDB is created. For hosting on IIS, I have tried LocalDB, SQLExpress & Azure SQL Server but none works.

I get "A task was canceled" error for which I am unable to find a solution.

This is the error I am getting:
[image: Azure Error]

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add more info about the error? As it stands I do not really understand what is not working.

Comment: Thanks @juunas for a quick reply. I have updated the description with the screenshot of error.

Comment: Thanks for adding the screenshot. So what is happening is that at startup the OpenId Connect middleware is trying to download the metadata document from Azure AD. It needs it to be able to validate tokens. Is your IIS behind a firewall or proxy?

Comment: Firewall & Proxy settings have been disabled. If I directly access the URL provided in the error, I am getting data. @juunas

Comment: @juunas for a better understanding I have exposed my website on https://careassist.datamatics.com

Also, if i host the application on azure as a web app, it is working smoothly.

Comment: How did you create this application on Azure Portal automatically and then publish it to another host?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT I created this application using Visual Studio 2015 and then using right-click I clicked on Configure Azure AD Authentication. After this configuration was done, it is working fine so I published on local IIS and it's not working.

Comment: Hi @ thanawalad.  I came acrosss this kind of issue with my Internet proxy. Acrroding to your error, your network may be interrupted by some configuration. Please end your proxy and test again, it may take few minutes to make effect.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT yes this issue is due to some proxy set in my company. When I tried running this application from my home machine, it's working fine.

I don't know what changes in proxy should I do. Can you tell me what changes you had done?

Comment: @thanawalad , I'm glad to hear that your app is working fine. I will write answer for your question, you can also accept it.:-)

Answer (score 0):

I came acrosss this kind of issue with my Internet proxy.

Acrroding to the error message, your network may be interrupted by some configuration.As junnas said,

> OpenId Connect middleware is trying to download the metadata document
>   from Azure AD. It needs it to be able to validate tokens

So, you can check if there is proxy or firewall again or run your App in another environment without a Proxy. Also,If you close a proxy on your machine,it may take few minutes to make effect.

Comment: I don't know which port to open and due to this I am unable to access my website from my local IIS.

Comment: Hi @thanawalad. You can check the port at `Properites>launchSettings.json`